# getting values from db using ajax and jquery final.html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i tried to fetch database values using jquery, but it's not working

code - final.html: http://pastebin.com/vMy5invc

api.php

```
<?php 
      $host = "localhost";
      $user = "root";
      $pass = "";
      $databaseName = "vhc";
      $tableName = "users";
      $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
      $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);
      $data = array();
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`name`,`email`,`location` FROM $tableName");
      while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
        {
          $data[] = $row;
        }
      echo json_encode( $data );          

       ?>
```

Comment: are you able to getting $row from database.

Comment: what php version are u using? msql_connect is outdated. perhaps this is your problem and you have to use mysqli

Comment: What is not working, what error do you get. Please **don't** use the old `mysql_` extension switch to `pdo` or `mysqli_`.

Comment: there's no problem with api.php  http://pastebin.com/vMy5invc this script is not working

Comment: Enable error reporting and see if you receive any errors.

Answer (score 0):

you shoud replace $tableName with ".$tableName."

```
<?php 
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "";
  $databaseName = "vhc";
  $tableName = "users";
  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);
  $data = array();
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`name`,`email`,`location` FROM ".$tableName."");
  while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
    {
      $data[] = $row;
    }
  echo json_encode( $data );          

   ?>
```

Comment: That would not solve anything since both queries would be the same. Also you have an extra " in your answer above it should be `mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`name`,`email`,`location` FROM " . $tableName);`

Comment: This is not extra " . because query started with one" and it should end with one" and when you use variable in query you should separate that  with "". this code is worked for me and I test that.

Comment: in double qouted strings variabels will be expanded so there is no need to do " . $tableName . "